converting .py to .exe, getting error OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
I have this python programme that runs fine in VS Code. I'm doing my first attempt at converting it to an exe. It's a basic programme where the user can pick multiple dinners from a list of 9 dinners and it will generate a shopping list. The ingredients are in csv files.
When I try to run the exe I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?
I tried asking chatGPT a few times but everything it suggested gave me errors, and honestly I've made so many changes that I dont know what I'm at anymore. Is this salvagable or do I just scrap it and start again?
Examples of suggestions from chatGPT and corresponding errors:
"you can use the input function from the PyInstaller.utils.cli module instead of the built-in input function."
and when I said that was giving me the error "Import "PyInstaller.utils.cli" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports(module) PyInstaller"
it said "use the PyInstaller.utils.inputhook module to handle input in a way that's compatible with PyInstaller-compiled executables"
but that also gave an error so then it said
"handle input in PyInstaller-compiled executables. We can use the input function along with sys.stdin redirection to ensure input works correctly."
which gave me the error ""Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 52, in <module OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid"
which also gavae an error so it replied
"We can use the PyInstaller hook to patch the sys.stdin stream" which is how I got to where I am now and still none the wiser.
Here is my current code:
import csv
import sys

def read_ingredients(file_name):
    ingredients = []
    with open(file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            ingredients.append(row[0])
    return ingredients

def generate_shopping_list(selected_dinners):
    all_ingredients = []
    for dinner in selected_dinners:
        file_name = dinner.lower().replace(" ", "") + ".csv"
        ingredients = read_ingredients(file_name)
        all_ingredients.extend(ingredients)
    unique_ingredients = list(set(all_ingredients))
    return unique_ingredients

def main():
    dinners = [
        "Spaghetti Bolognese",
        "Nasi Goreng",
        "Honey and Mustard Chicken Thighs",
        "Honey and Garlic Chicken Thighs",
        "Chocolate and Peanut Butter Overnight Oats",
        "Chickpea and Veg Soup",
        "Carbonara",
        "Beef Broccoli and Rice",
        "Banana Bread"
    ]

    print("Please pick which dinners you will have this week:")
    for index, dinner in enumerate(dinners, start=1):
        print(f"{index}. {dinner}")

    selected_indices = input("Enter the numbers corresponding to your selected dinners separated by spaces: ").split()
    selected_dinners = [dinners[int(index) - 1] for index in selected_indices]

    input("Press Enter to generate the shopping list...")

    shopping_list = generate_shopping_list(selected_dinners)

    print("\nShopping List:")
    for ingredient in shopping_list:
        print(ingredient)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # If the program is running as a bundled executable
        sys.stdin = open(0)
    main()


Add stdin=subprocess.PIPE in this file for python 3.8: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Libos.py line 983 to 991
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,bufsize=buffering)

Could you explain how this would address the problem presented in the question? Changing the library is not how you would usually fix problems with your code.
